# Clear Angular Material autocomplete on click

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I want reset value of angular material autocomplete on click
But I don't know how do.

My code :

```
  <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Give Rights" formControlName="selectedOption" aria-label="User" matInput  [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.displayName" (onSelectionChange)="setSelectedUser($event, user)">
                {{ user.displayName }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
        <button (click)="resetValue($event)">RESET</button>
    </mat-form-field>
```

TS :

```
    this.nameForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    selectedOption: new FormControl()
});    

    resetValue(){
    console.log("Value -> ", this.nameForm.value.selectedOption);
    this.nameForm.value.selectedOption = "test";
}
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 9):

First you need to get a handle to the control whose value you want to set, you can do this using FormGroup's get method

```
nameForm.get('selectedOption')
```

Then you can simply call the setValue method provided by Reactive Forms to set the value of 
 that control.

```
<button (click)="nameForm.get('selectedOption').setValue('')">RESET</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use two-way data binding to bind the input value to a property of the class, and use `resetValue` to act on that property.

---

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" ...
```

---

```
resetValue() {
  this.selectedOption = '';
}
```

See [working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obat6a)

Comment: Thank you, it's ok. I have update my post if you can check

Comment: Using ngModel is not a solution because a form control is being used.

Comment: @bugs - I know that - but other readers might not. It would be best if you deleted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was adding a local reference to the input control and using that to set the value to empty when an option is clicked:

```
input
    #matInput
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search"
    aria-label="Search"
    matInput
    [formControl]="search"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete
    #auto="matAutocomplete"
    (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)"
    panelWidth="auto">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items | async"
      [value]="item.Key"
      (click)="matInput.value=''">
      {{ item.Name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax doesn't look right. Try `this.nameForm.controls['selectedOption'].setValue('test');`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<pre>
//html
<input #inputSearch ........>

<button (click)="btnClick()"  ..........>click</button
//ts
import {ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
 @ViewChild('inputSearch') inputSearch: any;
 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,.............)
{
this.inputSearch = elementRef
}
btnClick(){
          this.inputSearch.nativeElement.value=null;
this.inputSearch.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
          }))
}

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Reactive forms can use the below to clear inputs.

```
//import Formbuilder in contructor
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

public form_details : FormGroup;

//Define the form names on ngOnInit
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form_details = this.fb.group({
      payment_type: ['', Validators.required],
      payment_date: [new Date(), Validators.required],
      total_amount: [
        { value: 0, disabled: false },
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(1)
        ],
      ],
      remarks: [''],
    });
}

// Then add mat-autocomplete inside form in template

<form [formGroup]="form_details" (submit)="onSubmit()">


          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-full-width">
            <mat-label>Payment type </mat-label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Pick one"
              matInput
              formControlName="payment_type"
              [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            />
            <mat-autocomplete
              #auto="matAutocomplete"
              [displayWith]="paymentTypeDisplayFn"
              (optionSelected)="onPaymentTypeChange($event)"
            >
              <mat-option
                *ngFor="let option of filteredPaymentTypes | async"
                [value]="option"
              >
                <small
                  ><b>{{ option.payment_code}}</b></small
                >
                / <small>{{ option.payment_type_name}}</small>
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <button
              *ngIf="form_details.get('payment_type').value"
              matSuffix
              mat-icon-button
              aria-label="Clear"
              (click)="handleClearInput('customer')"
            >
              <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-form-field>

</form>


// Add the following code in component

paymentTypeDisplayFn = (options) => {
    return options && options.payment_type_name
      ? options.payment_type_name+ '/' + options.payment_code
      : '';
  };

  private _filteredPaymentType(value: any): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(
      (option) =>
        option.payment_code.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
        option.payment_type_name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }

  onPaymentTypeChange(e) {
    // handle your own logic
  }

 handleClearInput(key) {
    this.payment_entry_details.patchValue({
      [key]: '',
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue as mat-autocomplete doesn't response properly to `control.reset`, and it only worked using the following solution. I will leave it here, hopefully it helps someone.

Here's my TypeScript code (deselecting each option manually): -

```js
reset(auto: MatAutocomplete): void {
  auto.options.forEach((c) => c.deselect());

  this.control.reset();
}
```

My HTML button code that should reset: -

```html
<button
    *ngIf="control.value"
    (click)="reset(auto)"
    mat-icon-button
    matIconSuffix
    type="button">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="mat:close"></mat-icon>
</button>
```