# Clear mat-autocomplete searchbox when making a selection instead of fill it out?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, search, angular-material

I am using the mat-autocomplete for my search functionality in my Angular application. As of now, the user searches for an item, and a dropdown list will appear. When user clicks on one of the items in the dropdown list, it automatically fills out the searchbar with that option. I would like that searchbar to instead become blank upon selection. Is there a way to make the searchbar clear instead of filling itself out in Angular mat-autocomplete?

Comment: Does this answer your question [Clear Angular Material autocomplete on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904900/clear-angular-material-autocomplete-on-click) ?

Comment: @EliezerVerasVargas Sort of. I think it's a bit different to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you set up a stackblitz I could help you with this.

Comment: @EliezerVerasVargas see this example here - https://stackblitz.com/angular/onljnxyyogy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts I would like it so that when clicking the option, instead of filling out the searchbar with the selected option, it should default back to being blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime an option is selected (listen to `optionSelected` to know that), clear the matInput value by calling `setValue("")` of the control linked to it. Also call the `blur()` function to remove the focus from the matInput.

[This is an example of how to do it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vamwyc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts)

Comment: This solution works for clicking with the mouse for the selection, but not for when using the arrow keys and Enter key. Do you know how to implement that as well?

Comment: Yes, I updated the example. It does exactly what you want now.